# analytics service which tells what users do inside app

Tags: mobile, analytics

I understand that Flurry gives analytics including: user retention, daily users, average active session time etc. But can I use it or some other service to tell me how many users have clicked a certain button, how much time users spend on a specific view etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Localytics (I work there), Flurry and other app analytics services support the recording of "events" that do exactly what you described. The events also have "attributes" that you can use to track additional details, like time (which we generally recommend bucketing -- ie, 0-5 seconds, 6-10 sections, etc.). Here's a link to our integration docs: http://www.localytics.com/docs/iphone-integration/

You might also want to track screens, and then combine events and screens into into conversion funnels.

Comment: can i use Flurry and Localytics simultaneously?
can i use the community version of Localytics for commercial?
thx